# conditional navigation in compose, without click

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on a compose screen, where on application open, i redirect user to profile page. And if profile is complete, then redirect to user list page.

my code is like below

```
@Composable
fun UserProfile(navigateToProviderList: () -> Unit) {

val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel = viewModel()

if(viewModel.userProfileComplete == true) {
    navigateToProviderList()
    return
}

else {
  //compose elements here
}

}
```

but the app is blinking and when logged, i can see its calling the above redirect condition again and again. when going through doc, its mentioned that we should navigate only through callbacks. How do i handle this condition here? i don't have onCLick condition here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Content of composable function can be called many times.

If you need to do some action inside composable, you need to use [side effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects)

In this case `LaunchedEffect` should work:

```
LaunchedEffect(viewModel.userProfileComplete == true) {
    if(viewModel.userProfileComplete == true) {
        navigateToProviderList()
    }
}
```

In the key(first argument of `LaunchedEffect`) you need to specify some key. Each time this key changes since the last recomposition, the inner code will be called. You may put `Unit` there, in this case it'll only be called once, when the view appears at the first place

Answer (score 1):

The LaunchedEffect did not work for me since I wanted to use it in UI thread but it wasn't for some reason :/
However, I made this for my self:

```
@Composable
fun <T> SelfDestructEvent(liveData: LiveData<T>, onEvent: (argument: T) -> Unit) {
    val previousState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val state by liveData.observeAsState(null)
    if (state != null && !previousState.value) {
        previousState.value = true
        onEvent.invoke(state!!)
    }
}
```

and you use it like this in any other composables:

```
SingleEvent(viewModel.someLiveData) {
        //your action with that data, whenever it was triggered, but only once
}
```